# Add flags gain as soon as net flags hits gain milestone

Tags: feature-request, flags

When you use all of your daily flags (default 10), and then you hit a +1 milestone (10 net helpful flags), that new flag doesn't get added straight away. Should we change this?

Comment: Ehh, looks like it'd be additional complexity for very little effect. Anyone who cares enough about flagging will hit the alotted maximum of 100 per day reasonably quickly.

Comment: Oh, yes. Good point. I was thinking maybe in terms of review queues...

Comment: So I got curious and mathed this out. You'd need 26 days of using up your flags to get to 100 maximum flags starting from 10 assuming every flag was helpful. In total you need 900 helpful flags to get to 100 a day.

Comment: That's quite interesting, thanks for that! Would you like to add an answer with that information?